# Multiclass classification with growing number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset of music listening history: when it was listened, where it was listened, what was the weather outside (and many more other features are coming soon) and a track_id as a label.

[image: Listening history]

I'm trying to predict the track I'll like at any given context (time + location + weather)

I want to run a multiclass classification on this data but I have these problems:

- Constantly mapping my track_ids to classes [0..distinct_trackid_count) and back
- I have a huge number of classes (tens of thousands)
- The number of classes is constantly growing, so I always have to retrain my algorithm from the start

I have a feeling that multiclass classification is not what I need here, and I need help in figuring out how to approach this problem

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would try to try some dimensionality reduction ideas first and then do a multi-class classification. Using simple clustering or feature extraction algorithms, you should be able to create some groups of songs (10-100 groups). If you treat these groups as classes, I think you will be able to learn the features pretty well to be able to recommend your preferred songs in a given environment. Not to mention the problem becomes very tractable after that.

However, if you are only after the one "perfect" song, K-nearest neighbours is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I might try (I'm not sure they'll work well):

1. Don't use classification, use regression: given the features, regression will return a rational number. Round it and pick the track with that ID / number to listen to. This should allow you to use any online learning algorithm and when a new song comes in, just feed your algorithm its features and target. This way, you don't have to do a full retraining for every new song;
2. Use a nearest neighbors approach: given a set of features, find the set of features from your songs that is closest to it, and pick that song. Also doesn't need full retraining, but might be inefficient.

You might also want to look into relational association rules.

Comment: just run a linear regression on this data => got nothing sensible (negative rationals) :)

Comment: @NizamutdinovAdel - if your song IDs aren't negative then negative results don't make sense, you should at least get something positive. It sounds like a bug in your implementation. Also, linear might not be the best for this.

Comment: I see how #2 makes sense, but I really don't understand how #1 can work out if there's no logical ordering in the track IDs...?!